# Accessing User Credential Value from Azure.Identity

Tags: visual-studio, azure-active-directory, azure-identity

I have connected my Visual studio to `Azure Active Directory` by setting and manually entering pass/email.

This credential shows when I go to `Azure Serice Authenticator` in Visual Studio under tools.

I want to access the ID associated.
I came across this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet) , and I want the `AZURE_USERNAME` , which must be associated with the id logged in.

I am unable to get a way by which I can access this value.

---

Does it mean that I can only access it if I explicitly set such value ?

--
Alternatively , is there any way by which I can access the Email ID of user signed in to Visual studio / or signed into Windows and not just User name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes of course we should preset environment variables.

Then we can use them for `EnvironmentCredential` authentication. The reverse will not work.

You can call Microsoft Graph API to get the user information.

Sample reference [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#example-2-signed-in-user-request).

You can implement the graphServiceClient  like this:

```
var credential = new DefaultAzureCredential();
var token = credential.GetToken(
    new Azure.Core.TokenRequestContext(
        new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" }));

var accessToken = token.Token;
var graphServiceClient = new GraphServiceClient(
    new DelegateAuthenticationProvider((requestMessage) =>
    {
        requestMessage
        .Headers
        .Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", accessToken);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }));
```

A [blog](https://www.rahulpnath.com/blog/defaultazurecredential-from-azure-sdk/#microsoft-graph-api) for your reference.